# On the critical points of $e^x \sin{y}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm asked to find the critical points of $f(x,y) = e^x \sin{y}$.

I've found that $f_{x}(x,y) = e^x \sin{y}$ and $f_{y}(x,y) = e^x \cos{y}$,

so that $f_{x}(x,y)+f_{y}(x,y) = 0 \implies e^x (\sin{y}+\cos{y}) = \sqrt{2}e^x \sin(y+\pi/4) = 0$

So $y = -\pi/4+2\pi k, 3\pi/4+2\pi k$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ but this implies $e^x = 0$, which is impossible, right?

Comment: Why are you considering $f_{x}(x,y)+f_{y}(x,y)$ ? You should be looking at points where the gradient is $0$.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Isn't that the same thing? e.g. $f_{x}(x, y) = 0, ~ f_{y}(x, y) = 0 \implies f_{x}(x, y)+f_{y}(x, y) = 0$?

Comment: $f_{x}(x, y) = 0, ~ f_{y}(x, y) = 0 \implies f_{x}(x, y)+f_{y}(x, y) = 0$ is certainly true, but the converse is dead wrong.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM But I'm not using the converse, or is that not clear?

Comment: You chose the path of the converse though, don't you see it ?

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM I believe you, but I don't see it. Do you mind explaining it a bit more? It's likely that I have a deeper misunderstanding 'cause I have been doing problems this way all day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37833/discussion-between-user129566-and-legranddodom).

Comment: Let's say that $f_x = 1, f_y = -1$. Then $f_x + f_y = 0$, but $f_x$ nor $f_y$ is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find $f_x(x,y) = 0$ and $f_y(x,y) = 0$ independently.

But there is not place where both are 0.

Comment: What did I do wrong? $f_{x}(x, y) = 0, ~ f_{y}(x, y) = 0 \implies f_{x}(x, y)+f_{y}(x, y) = 0.$

Comment: @user129566: $\Longrightarrow$ but not $\Longleftarrow$.